# Ubuntu Server requires service restart every few days

Tags: apache2, mysql, process, remote, kill

I'm new here and I hope you can help me out this time.

I have a MySQL server which receives many requests from my other servers...daily up to 1000 requests (HTTP and remote MySQL).

However, for some reason, if I don't restart apache and MySQL service every 5-10 days it starts to slow down.

I was thinking of doing a cron job which would do service restart every X days.. but in that case, I risk the service restart once I'm running some operation...

How can I check which process is doing the problem or just simply maybe adding some apache rule which would force kill process if it's running for longer than 10 minutes?

Thanks.

Comment: You can restart your MySQL service without loss of data, or risking data integrity. However, your server will briefly appear unavailable. If that is really a big deal, you should consider a MySQL cluster or some other form of load balancing.